# Inconsistent method declarations in duplicated types

Tags: c++-cli

I'm making a class in c++-cli, and I added an extra argument to one of my functions. The name of the extra argument was int row,and when I add that I get this error:

> LNK2022   metadata operation failed (80131187) : Inconsistent method declarations in duplicated types (types: query; methods: Read_DB)

When I remove that extra argument I added, the error goes away. If I remove the argument column_index, it also goes away. But if I remove one of the String^ arguments, it still stays. I'm not sure what the error is, here's both my .h and the functions definition in the .cpp file of code:

Header:

```cpp
#ifndef DATA_BASE
#define DATA_BASE

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Data::SqlClient;

ref class ConnectDB{
protected:
    SqlConnection^ cnn;
    bool state;

public:
    String^ db;

    bool ConnectDataBase();
    bool DisconnectDataBase(void);
};

ref class Query : public ConnectDB {
private:
    ~Query(void);
public:
    bool Create_Table(String^ name, String^ columns);

    String^ Read_DB(String^ column, String^ table, int column_index, int row);
    bool Write_DB(String^ path, String^ msg);
};

#endif
```

cpp file:

```cpp
String^ Query::Read_DB(String^ column, String^ table, int column_index, int row) {
    String^ output;
    String^ sql = "SELECT " + column + " FROM " + table;

    try {
        SqlCommand^ command;
        SqlDataReader^ dataReader;


        command = gcnew SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
        dataReader = command->ExecuteReader();

        std::cout << "Reading data from Database...\n";

        int counter;
        while (dataReader->Read()) {
            counter++;

            if(counter == row)
                output = (String^)dataReader->GetValue(column_index);
        }

        //command->Dispose();
        dataReader->Close();
    }
    catch (Exception^ e) {
        Console::WriteLine(e);

        std::cout << "Failed to query database\n";
        return "0";
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are linking against something (object, library etc) which uses the same header, but did not get recompiled after the header change. The [`LNK2022`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2022?view=msvc-160) page suggests some troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to fix the problem I just deleted the debug folder and restarted my application. It had something to do with changing the name of the object.